# Get dbt cloud job id inside a dbt macro

Tags: dbt, dbt-cloud

I'm trying to get the DBT_CLOUD_JOB_ID - as dbt_artifact seems to do ([here](https://github.com/brooklyn-data/dbt_artifacts/blob/73cb50446532b5d0acd93a3080a252dc1d1a9514/macros/upload_invocations.sql#L41)):

```
{ set dbt_cloud_job_id = env_var('DBT_CLOUD_JOB_ID', '') %}
{{ log("LOG dbt_cloud_job_id: " ~ dbt_cloud_job_id) }}
```

Prints:

```
LOG dbt_cloud_job_id:
```

But I'm not succeeding. It returns empty.
is there a better way to get this dbt cloud job id or am I missing something here?

[EDIT]

The problem was a syntax error `{% %}`

```
{% set dbt_cloud_job_id = env_var('DBT_CLOUD_JOB_ID', '') %}
```

Comment: I believe that environment variable is expecting a dbt Cloud environment, so unless you run that log() within a dbt Cloud job, you will not get anything printed. To print it locally, you would need to set it up elsewhere (e.g. in an .env file)